# Importing Module in another File(Python) shows blank result, while working properly in cmd

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python, and I've faced a problem that won't leave a clue. I've checked whether the project files are in the same directory, and they are, since no error message pops up when I import my Hello.py file. in cmd, it works, showing results, but it won't work in the script I wrote in Pycharm! Thanks.

```
#Hello.py
PI=3.141592
class Math:
    def solv(self, r):
        return PI*(r**2)

def sum(a, b):
    return a+b
```

The upper code is what I want to import. Below shows how I imported and used the module.

```
#hi.py
from Hello import *
a = Math()
print(a.solv(1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fsy5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oDMq.png)

Comment: Please include all relevant code as **text** in your question, not as images!

Comment: I've added the code! Thanks

Comment: What does "shows blank result" mean?  You're printing a floating point number from your main file, and there is no sys.exit() in your code.  If running that file via Python does not produce any output, you've got something fundamentally wrong.  You should be getting either error information or a printed floating point number, regardless of anything that happened before the print statement (again, short of an explicit exit() call).  Are you sure that code is actually running?  Replace the code in hi.py with print("Hi!") as a starting point.

Comment: I'm a PyCharm user too. although not on Windows.  I just created your two files at an arbitrary place in an existing project source tree.  I then right-clicked inside the text of the "hi.py" file and selected "Run 'hi'".  Your program worked flawlessly! :) - I'd check your Run/Debug Configuration and/or try running the program the way I just did.

Comment: Works for me in 3.7.0. I also feel like mentioning the builtin `sum` that you are overwriting works pretty easily as `sum([a, b])` anyway.